# Multiple table input for mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, accumulo

I am thinking of doing a mapreduce using accumulo tables as input.
Is there a way to have 2 different tables as input, the same way it exists for the multiple files input like `addInputPath` ?
Or is it possible to have one input from a file and the other one from a table with `AccumuloInputFormat` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at `AccumuloMultiTableInputFormat`. The Accumulo manual demonstrates how to use it [here](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.8/accumulo_user_manual.html#_accumulomultitableinputformat_options).

Example Usage:

```
job.setInputFormat(AccumuloInputFormat.class);

AccumuloMultiTableInputFormat.setConnectorInfo(job, user, new PasswordToken(pass));
AccumuloMultiTableInputFormat.setMockInstance(job, INSTANCE_NAME);

InputTableConfig tableConfig1 = new InputTableConfig();
InputTableConfig tableConfig2 = new InputTableConfig();

Map<String, InputTableConfig> configMap = new HashMap<String, InputTableConfig>();
configMap.put(table1, tableConfig1);
configMap.put(table2, tableConfig2);

AccumuloMultiTableInputFormat.setInputTableConfigs(job, configMap);
```

See the unit test for AccumuloMultiTableInputFormat [here](https://github.com/apache/accumulo/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/mapreduce/AccumuloMultiTableInputFormatTest.java) for some additional information.

Note, that unlike normal multiple inputs, you can't specify different Mappers to run on each table. Although, its not a massive problem in this case since the incoming Key/Value types are the same and you can use:

```
RangeInputSplit split = (RangeInputSplit)c.getInputSplit();
String tableName = split.getTableName();
```

To workout which table the records are coming from (taken from the Accumulo manual) in your mapper.